# I want to Link my NEXT.js project with a static website

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, content-management-system, strapi

I have a website that I developed using HTML, CSS it's a static website, but now I created a blog project using NEXT.js Integrated with Strapi API. **My question is how I can link my static website with my Next.js project?**

**I tried using Link tags but it didn't work**

```
import Link from "next/link";

function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
    <>
      <HomeHeader />
      <Link href="./index.html">
        <a>Static Page</a>
      </Link>
      <HomeLatestPosts Posts={posts} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You could just use a regular `<a>` element for that

Comment: What do you mean by `Link`? You want to show a full HTML page within your Nextjs app or just a navigation Link to that website?

Comment: Just navigations links to my full HTML files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the router or the "Link" component. Just use the standard html a tag with a href attribute.

```
 <a href="insert link"> </a>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, but the issue is the the URL is like this http://localhost:3000/index.html My Next.js project(Blog) will be a sub-page of my static website. is it possible to link this project as a sub-page to my static site?